# How to I keep it under other animation and prevent animation interupting other tag's animation?

Tags: html, css, animation

While I run this code, it worked perfectly and as I wanted, the problem occurred while I added  `animation: Fade_Out 7.5s 1 forwards;` in `.text2{}`, the MUM {of .text2} overlapped Happy Birthday {of text1}. I want the second line to come under the first line, but the animation line made it overlap on the first one. Still I want to use the `Fade_Out` animation. Thanks in advance.

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
body{
  background: #000;
}
.container{
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 100%;
}
.container span{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
}
.text1{
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  animation: text 4s 1, Fade_Out 7.5s 1 forwards;
}
.text2{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #12E6E3;
}
.text3{
  color: #F10000;
  font-size: 20px;
  animation: text 4s 1, Fade_Out 7.5s 1 forwards;
}
@keyframes Fade_Out
{
  0%
  {
    Opacity: 1;
  }
  75%
  {
    Opacity: 1;
  }
  100%
  {
    Opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes text {
  0%{
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: -40px;
  }
  30%{
    letter-spacing: 25px;
    margin-bottom: -40px;
  }
  85%{
    letter-spacing: 8px;
    margin-bottom: -40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head> 
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
  <title>Animation Text</title> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <div class="container"> 
   <span class="text1">Happy Birthday</span> 
   <span class="text2" id="Cool">Mum!</span> 
   <span class="text3">My Dear and lovely</span> 
  </div> 
  <canvas id="Can"></canvas> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `z-index` for layer indexing, refer the *css comments* and *live code demo* too..**

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
body {
  background: #000;
}
.container {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
}
.container span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
}
.text1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  /*indexing the layers*/
  z-index:9;
  animation: text 4s 1, Fade_Out 7.5s 1 forwards;
}
.text2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #12e6e3;
  animation: Fade_Out 7.5s 1 forwards;
}
.text3 {
  color: #f10000;
  font-size: 20px;
  /*fix text line heights for more*/
  line-height:50px;
  animation: text 4s 1, Fade_Out 7.5s 1 forwards;
}
@keyframes Fade_Out {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes text {
  0% {
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: -40px;
  }
  30% {
    letter-spacing: 25px;
    margin-bottom: -40px;
  }
  85% {
    letter-spacing: 8px;
    margin-bottom: -40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Animation Text</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <span class="text1">Happy Birthday</span>
    <span class="text2" id="Cool">Mum!</span>
    <span class="text3">My Dear and lovely</span>
  </div>
  <canvas id="Can"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked well and I can now proceed for a birthday surprise to my mother!